# I can't understand this line - dereferencing an address of private member variable or what?

Tags: c++, stl

I asked a question while ago [about accessing the underlying container of STL adapters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185252/is-there-a-way-to-access-the-underlying-container-of-stl-container-adaptors). I got a very helpful answer:

```
template <class T, class S, class C>
    S& Container(priority_queue<T, S, C>& q) {
        struct HackedQueue : private priority_queue<T, S, C> {
            static S& Container(priority_queue<T, S, C>& q) {
                return q.*&HackedQueue::c;
            }
        };
    return HackedQueue::Container(q);
}

int main()
{
    priority_queue<SomeClass> pq;
    vector<SomeClass> &tasks = Container(pq);
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't understand this line:

```
return q.*&HackedQueue::c;
```

What does this line do? Also, how could that line access the private container in `priority_queue` that is passed to the function `Container`?

Comment: I think you might want to read about my slightly sarcastic "hidden features of C++" entry: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75538/hidden-features-of-c/1065606#1065606 :)

Comment: @Alcon, Man my answer wasn't really good, I preferred to delete it, I appreciate it man :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Think of it like this:

```
(q).*(&HackedQueue::c);
```

First, you have HackedQueue::c, which is just the name of a member variable.  Then you take &HackedQueue::c, which is a pointer to that member variable.  Next you take `q`, which is just an object reference.  Then you use the "bind pointer to member by reference" operator `.*` to bind the member variable referred to by the member-variable pointer using `q` as the `this`.

As to the private member issue, `priority_queue::c` is only protected, not private, so it should come as no surprise that when you derive from `priority_queue`, that you can access its protected members.

Comment: Thanks but 'c' is a member variable. Which is the container inside the std::priority_queue.

Comment: Sorry, yes.  It's a member variable, but the bind to member operator is still the same (just like `.` gets used for both jobs.

Comment: `&(HackedQueue::c)` will actually try to get a pointer to the member variable, and fail because c is not a static member. Common pit-fall :) Between the & and the member name cannot be anything except whitespace. for example: `struct A { int a; }; struct B : A { void f() { *&(A::a) = 0; this->*&A::a = 0; } };` Notice the difference: `&(A::a)` gets an int* to the actual member object (it's sometimes useful if a is hidden by a same name in the derived class), while `(&A::a)` gets a member pointer that stores the member offset. Anyway i understand it probably wasn't meant to be real code :)