# Compare a Queue and a Stack's content

Tags: c++, recursion, stack, queue, equality

Suppose we have in c++, using STL Stack and Queue

```
    Stack:      [1 2 3 4 5] <=>
    Queue:   => [5 4 3 2 1] =>
```

What is the most elegant way to recursively check that the data entries are the same in terms of content and order? Say the stack and queue shown above have the same data and same order.

I'm having a problem conceptually understanding what to do because the data pop() in opposite order.

Comment: [Whathaveyoutried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)? why do you need to recursively check?

Comment: I can't conceptually envision a way to do it, so I haven't tried anything. However, it did just occur to me that I can peek the front AND back of a queue according to STL queue. I think this helps.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't [for a class](https://wiki.engr.illinois.edu/display/cs225sp11/Lab06)? Especially since it seems to be around the same time. This might be considered cheating

Answer (score 0):

A partially recursive solution would be to recursively pop all the elements from the queue in an auxiliary stack and then check if the auxiliary stack and the original stack are the same. This check can be done also recursively.

Comment: That's very true; it seems thought there is a way to do it without creating a new queue or stack.

Answer (score 0):

No need for recursion, this would be a useless waste of resources. No need to mutate your `queue` and `stack` either (in other words, this works even on `const`'s).

Assuming your `std::stack` and `std::queue` both internally use the same type of underlying container (which should be `std::dequeue` if you used the default) then you can access the protected members `c` (your real containers) of both `queue` and `stack` and compare them using operator `==`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>

template<typename Adapter>
typename Adapter::container_type const& getContainer(const Adapter& adapter) {
  struct AccessProtected : private Adapter {
    static typename Adapter::container_type const& getContainer(const Adapter& adapter) { return adapter.*&AccessProtected::c; }
  };
  return AccessProtected::getContainer(adapter);
}

int main() {
  std::queue<int> queue;
  std::stack<int> stack;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    queue.push(i);
    stack.push(i);
  }
  std::cout << (getContainer(queue) == getContainer(stack) ? "equal" : "not equal") << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Now, if you use different containers types as the underlying implementation of `queue` and `stack`, you can still use that same `getContainer()` technique to obtain containers that are sorted in the same order: both `queue::push()` and `stack::push()` call the underlying container's `push_back()` method, it's only when you `pop()` (and similar operations) that the reversing happens for `stack`. Since those underlying containers will be in the same order, you can then compare things more easily (left as an exercise to the reader ;)).

**Credit:** I was too lazy to reimplement a protected member accessor again, so I shamelessly copied and modified [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185252/is-there-a-way-to-access-the-underlying-container-of-stl-container-adaptors).

Answer (score 0):

If by recursion, you do not mean a recursive function call, but just looping, then here's an answer. The function first checks if the stack and queue are the same size. If they aren't the same size, the function returns false. The function has a local stack object that gets the stack parameter's elements, in order to be popped in the reverse order as the stack parameter that is passed in. Then a loop checks each front/top element of stack and queue for equality. If equal, the loop continues to the next iteration. If not equal, the function returns false. If the loop finishes without returning false, the function returns true.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

bool check(stack<int> stackPar, queue<int> queuePar)
{

    if (stackPar.size() != queuePar.size())
    {
        return false;
    }

    stack<int> reverseStack;

    for (int i = 0, initialSize = stackPar.size(); i < initialSize; ++i)
    {
        reverseStack.push(stackPar.top());
        stackPar.pop();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < reverseStack.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (reverseStack.top() == queuePar.front())
        {
            reverseStack.pop();
            queuePar.pop();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    stack<int> myStack;
    queue<int> myQueue;

    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i)
    {
        myStack.push(i);
        myQueue.push(i);
    }

    cout << "Stack and queue are ";
    cout << ( check(myStack, myQueue) ? "equal." : "not equal." ) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works, but that's a lot of copies. Depending on the actual size of the containers this could be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

U may not pop them simultaneously, u can try to pop one(use something record it) ADT(dont pop queue, pop stack), and to the base(size==1), and u compare and made some change to the queue,  and returns. Then do something with the recorder and the currently queue's front after every recursion calls, you will find the answer.