# How to merge two priority_queue?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have two `priority_queue` with `float` like this:

```
std::priority_queue<float> queue1;
std::priority_queue<float> queue2;
```

And I need to merge them. But STL `merge` algorithm do not allow working with the `priority_queue` directly:

```
merge(
  queue1.begin(), queue2.end(),
  queue2.begin(), queue2.end(),
  queue1
);
```

Is there  a way to merge `priority_queue` without using auxiliary data structures?

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to pop elements from one queue and push them into the other one.

Comment: The standard library doesn't contain an algorithm to merge two heaps. Since `priority_queue` is just a wrapper around the standard library's heap algorithms, you don't have a merge feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`priority_queue` is a container adapter, not a regular standard container. In particular, it does not offer the `begin()` and `end()` member functions. Therefore, you will have to pop the elements out of one queue and push them into the other:

```
while (!queue2.empty())
{
    queue1.push(queue2.top());
    queue2.pop();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Adding to Andy's answer, an important optimization is to always merge elements from the smaller priority queue into the larger one. This can be done using `std::swap`:

```
// merge elements into dest from src
template<typename T>
void merge_pq(std::priority_queue<T>& dest, std::priority_queue<T>& src) {
  if (dest.size() < src.size()) {
    std::swap(dest, src);
  }
  while (!src.empty()) {
    dest.push(src.top());
    src.pop();
  }
}
```

This can make a real difference, especially when the two priority queues have very different sizes.

In the most recent Facebook Hacker Cup programming contest, there was a question that required you to merge priority queues as part of a larger algorithm. If you didn't do this optimization, your code would take too long and you would not get the question correct. This happened to me; my code took over 5 minutes to run without this optimization, but less than 10 seconds when I added this optimization after the contest was over. I did not receive credit for the question. Hopefully if you're reading this and encounter a similar problem you'll be more successful :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of processing them one by one, as suggested before, to achieve better performance you can ["steal" underlying containers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1385520/8414561) from queues, merge them and construct another `priority_queue` from the merged container:

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/1385520/8414561
template <class T, class S, class C>
S& Container(std::priority_queue<T, S, C>& q) {
    struct HackedQueue : private std::priority_queue<T, S, C> {
        static S& Container(std::priority_queue<T, S, C>& q) {
            return q.*&HackedQueue::c;
        }
    };
    return HackedQueue::Container(q);
}

int main()
{
    std::priority_queue<int> queue1{std::less<int>{}, {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}};
    std::priority_queue<int> queue2{std::less<int>{}, {10,14,15}};

    auto v1 = std::move(Container(queue1));
    auto v2 = std::move(Container(queue2));

    v1.insert(v1.end(), std::make_move_iterator(v2.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(v2.end()));

    std::priority_queue<int>queue3{std::less<int>{}, std::move(v1)};
    while (!queue3.empty()) {
        std::cout << queue3.top() << std::endl;
        queue3.pop();
    }
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff4012f050d31f6f).