# What does the .*& operator do?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I stumbled across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1185252/315052), which had an answer that used an odd construct:

```
typedef std::queue<int> Q;
typedef Q::container_type C;

C & get (Q &q)
{
    struct hack : private Q {
        static C & get (Q &q) {
            return q.*&hack::c;
        }
    };
    return hack::get(q);
}
```

I generally follow that `q` has access to its own `c` member that is being referenced by the `get` function. But, I am at a loss to clearly explain it. What is happening exactly with the `.*&`, and why is it allowed?

Comment: That's two operators: `.*` and `&`.

Comment: I'm thinking that trick might have been inspired by http://stackoverflow.com/a/1065606/962089

Comment: @chris That's a classy finding. Thank you for this!

Comment: gotta say that this looks indeed more interesting than operator `-->` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-the-operator (and had no idea why one would use such thing), +1

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
typedef std::queue<int> Q;
```

`Q` is a `queue` adapted container.

```
typedef Q::container_type C;
```

`C` is the underlying container of the `Q` -- which is a `deque<int>`.

```
C & get (Q &q) {
```

`get` takes a `queue` and returns a `deque`.  In fact it returns the `deque` that the `queue` wraps: by conventional means, this is not possible.

```
  struct hack : private Q {
```

`hack` is a type local to the function.  It inherits from `Q` and has only one static member function.  From its name, you may suspect it is a hack.  You are right.

No `hack` is ever instantiated.

```
    static C & get (Q &q) {
```

`hack::get` has the same signature as `get` itself.  In fact we delegate all of the work of `get` to this method.

```
      return q.*&hack::c;
```

this line needs to be broken down.  I will do it in more lines:

```
      using mem_ptr_t = C Q::*; // aka typedef C Q::*mem_ptr_t;
      mem_ptr_t c_mem_ptr = &hack::c;
      C& ret = q.*c_mem_ptr;
      return ret;
```

The first line defines the type of a member pointer to a field of type `C` within a `Q`.  Both the C++11 and C++03 ways of naming this type are ugly.

The second line gets a member pointer to the field `c` in `Q`.  It does this through the hole in the type system of C++.  `&hack::c` is logically of type `C hack::*` -- a pointer to a member of type `C` within a class of type `hack`.  In fact, that is why we can access it in a `static` member of `hack`.  But the `c` in question is actually in `Q`, so the actual type of the expression in C++ is `C Q::*`: a pointer to a member variable of `Q`.

You cannot directly get this member pointer within `hack` -- `&Q::c` is illegal, but `&hack::c` is not.

You can think of member pointers as 'typed offsets' into another type: `&hack::c` is the "offset" of `c` within `Q` together with knowing it is of type `C`.  Now this isn't really true -- it is some opaque value that tells the compiler how to get `c` from `Q` -- but it helps to think about it that way (and it may be implemented that way in simple cases).

We then use this member pointer together with a `Q&` to get the `c` out of the `Q`.  Getting a member pointer is constrained by protected: using it is not!  The way we do it is with operator `.*`, which is the member dereference operator, which you can pass either member function pointers *or* members on the right, and class instances on the left.

`instance .* member_ptr` is an expression that finds the member "pointed to" by `member_ptr` within the `instance`.  In the original code, everything was done on one line:

```
instance .* &class_name::member_name
```

so it looked like there was an operator `.*&`.

```
    }
  };
```

and then we close up the static method and `hack` class, and:

```
  return hack::get(q);
}
```

call it.  This technique gives access to `protected` state: without it, `protected` members can only be accessed in child classes of the same instance.  Using this, we can access `protected` members of *any* instance, without violating any bit of the standard.

Comment: I notice you never gave the type of `c_mem_ptr`, although that's key to the entire trick (and a violation of type theory -- it ought to be `C& hack::*`)

Comment: @BenVoigt: Holly cow, that was a subtle comment. Thanks for that insight. I missed this from the referenced answer: *The key point is that the type of a member pointer is bound to the class that actually contains said member - not to the class that you specified when taking the address.*

Comment: @BenVoigt: No, it's C Q::*.

Comment: @Jamboree: That is Ben's point. That is what it is, but not what it ought to be.

Comment: @BenVoigt ok, I highlighted the hole in the type system, and included explicit types, and removed `auto`.  Such a horrible way to name a type.

Comment: @jxh On top of that, I added a paragraph or two extra about `.*&`.  I like the line-by-line surrounds, as the entire bit of code is more than a bit obtuse, and understanding the context is important.  I could have instead created a simpler example I suppose.

Answer (score 8):

It's a hack, as the nomenclature indicates.

`.*` takes an object on the left side, and a member pointer on the right side, and resolves the pointed-to member of the given object. `&` is, of course, the referencing operator; `&Class::Member` returns a member pointer, which cannot by itself be dereferenced but which can be used with the `.*` and `->*` operators (the latter being the wackiest of all C++ operators). So `obj .* &Class::Member` has exactly the same *effect* as `obj.Member`.

The reason this more complicated version is being used comes down to a loophole in protection semantics; basically, it allows access to `protected` members of a base class object, even if the object is not of the same type as the class doing this dirty hack.

Personally, I think the trick is too clever by half. I'd ordinarily* write such code as:

```
struct hack : private Q {
    static C & get (Q &q) {
        return static_cast<hack &>(q).c;
    }
};
```

Which is technically slightly less safe, but doesn't obscure what's going on.

.* Well, ordinarily I'd avoid writing such a thing at all. But I literally did this earlier today, so I can't really throw stones.

Comment: I wouldn't call UB "slightly less safe".

Comment: @T.C. I would, since no compilers actually do something unexpected in that case. The only thing to worry about is future-proofing, though it's difficult to see how any compiler would ever behave differently.

Comment: Your 'less safe' version relies on parent classes being stored as prefixes, and/or the child adding no elements before it.  This is only guaranteed for standard layout types: your `hack` may or may not be standard layout.  Once a type is not standard layout, the compiler is free to (say) reposition elements based on profile guidance, insert profiling data that differs in size at the front of hack and Q that differs in size, add canary data to detect UB, or a whole myriad of other stuff your code would break on.

Comment: Heck: it could prove no well defined path to access the field exists, and eliminate it.

Comment: @Yakk Could, yes, but doesn't. As I said, despite what compilers *could* do, none of them *do it*.

Comment: Pasting in your code does not compile for me with the code in my example.

Comment: Your approach doesn't compile on gcc or clang.

Comment: @Barry was a stray `const`.