# C++ reverse a priority queue in place

Tags: c++, priority-queue, heap

Hi I was wondering if given a std::priority_queue is there are a way to change the heap order from min heap to max heap and vice versa? And I'm not talking about defining a priority queue with greater, what I mean is we already have a priority_queue with some elements.

I would basically want to print elements in reversed order from priority queue while popping.

Now I'm aware that the elements could be loaded up to a stack for example, and then popped from it, that would change the order, but I would like to do it in-place, without using additional memory, or writing my own heap implementation for that matter.

Is there a way to do it?

Example:

```
std::priority_queue<int> pq{};

pq.push(1);
pq.push(2);
pq.push(3);

while(!pq.empty()){

   std::cout << pq.top();
   pq.pop(); //this would print 321, but I would simply like 123, reversed.
   //but don't change the declaration of the priority_queue. Reverse it when   it has its elements inside of it.

}
```

Comment: You can't do this in place.  The order of the queue is set when you declare it and cannot be changed.

Comment: I don't mean changing the rules of it, I'm talking about popping it's elements

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Maybe you show a [mcve], so SO users can offer a solution based on your code but not on your words.

Comment: queues are FIFO, you can't change that either

Comment: I don't see a compelling reason for making this harder than it needs to be. Declare the `priorirty_queue` with the ordering you actually want.

Comment: There is a reason in a specific problem I'm solving... I need to be able to pop the minimum element from the heap, but then after all the calculations are done on it I want to print elements from it from maximum to minimum. This can be achieved with stack, but I was wondering if it's possible without creating addtional memory, maybe move the priority queue or something. Is there no operation that would call heapify on all it's elements but with max heap rules for example?

Comment: If that's the case, it sounds like you have the wrong data structure.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to use multiset, because it's Red black tree, and binary heap just fits better. In theory if I was about to implement a binary heap on my own it would be possible, but doing that is an overkill... Unless You have better ideas..

Comment: std::priority_queue does not have API for this. Meaning it is impossible to do reliably. You need a feature that std::priority_queue doesn't support, ergo, use a different data structure. Red black tree may be complicated (depending on the flavour), but for example skip list is not.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_priority_queue ?

Comment: double ended priority queue sounds badass but is there a stl thing for it?

Comment: it's literally implemented with std::set tho

Comment: https://github.com/nmcclatchey/Priority-Deque

Comment: what about this? :D

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29289974/what-does-the-operator-do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have tagged the question with [heap](/questions/tagged/heap). This a great hint, why don't use it instead of the priority queue?

```
std::vector<int> pq{};

pq.push_back(1);
pq.push_back(2);
pq.push_back(3);

// possibly first sort order
std::make_heap(pq.begin(), pq.end(), std::less<>{});

// ...

// Reorder
std::make_heap(pq.begin(), pq.end(), std::greater<>{});

while(!pq.empty()) {
  std::pop_heap(pq.begin(), pq.end(), std::greater<>{});
  std::cout << pq.back();
  pq.pop_back();
  // The loop will print 123
}
```

You can change a compare function in a heap with remaking it at any time.

Comment: Will this heapify in place? the make_heap function Well the reason would be that I wouldl have to make_heap everytime I insert a new element, because after inserting a new element I'm removing (popping) smallest one. and that repeats in a loop

Comment: Yes, of course, it works with a container elements.

Comment: No, you call make_heap only once with a dirty container. You call push_heap on each new element inserted with container's push_back.

Comment: @John_Cena If you need to reverse the heap order every time you interact with it, both heap and priority_queue are the wrong data structures. Consider `std::set` or a sorted `std::deque`.

Comment: Okey, so If i have a heap that was made with std::make_heap as pq, at any point of time i can push an element like to priority queue and at any point of time I can heapify all it's contents in place with make_heap? What is the catch here? Why isn't this used instead of priority queue if it has more functionalities? Why am i hearing about this for the first time?

Comment: Not everytime, just once. But after it worked as min heap for a while for example. then turn it into max heap, but in place.

Comment: @John_Cena: `std::priority_queue` is just a wrapper around the `std::heap` apis to enforce that they're correctly used.  The advantage is that you can't access the underlying `std::vector`, and therefore can't invalidate the heap.

Comment: @273K: `std::make_heap` changed in C++20, but has always existed since C++98 too.

Comment: @John_Cena: Yes. Exactly like `std::vector` is simply a wrapper around `new T[]`.

Comment: Does that mean all of you described here can be used with C++17? That's kind of what I'm limited to unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, what's described here works in every official version of C++, ever.

Comment: I mean make_heap, is it in c++17, because 273K said it's new algorithm since C++20

Comment: @MooingDuck Thanks. I've confused it with ranges::make_heap manual.

Comment: @John_Cena: `ranges::make_heap` is new.  `std::make_heap` is old. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap

Comment: Actually as I used it now, std::less<>{} will make a max heap, lol. weird