# Getting index of an element in a std::queue by its value

Tags: c++, stl, queue

Is there a simple way to get the position of an element in a `std::queue` by its value in C++?

For example:

```
std::queue<int> numbers;

numbers.push(7);
numners.push(4);
numbers.push(11);

int position = numbers.getPosition(4); //should be 1
```

Comment: This smells very strongly to be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). If you really need to get the index of (or iterator to) an element from a `std::queue` from its value, your code design is flawed: don't use a `std::queue` if you need this. (Also, there may be no unique index, depending on the values: what if they are all the same?)

Comment: Note that the STL containers were not designed to be **publicly** derived from, since they don't have *virtual destructors*. I'm not doing that here, but someone can still publicly derive from `std::queue` as long as the risks are understood.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to get the index of an element you should probably consider using an [`std::deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) container instead of a `std::queue` container *adapter*, as already suggested in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54310728/8012646).

---

If you still want to stick to to the [`std::queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) container adapter for some other reason, you should know that it does provide access to the underlying container through the *protected* data member `c`.

You could derive from `std::queue` in order to access the underlying container and use the [`std::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) function template for finding an element in that container with such a value. Then, simply return the position of that element by using [`std::distance()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <queue>

template<typename T>
class Queue: std::queue<T> {
public:
   auto getPosition(const T& val) const {
      auto it = std::find(this->c.begin(), this->c.end(), val);
      return std::distance(this->c.begin(), it);
   }
// ...
};
```

If the element is not found, the index will correspond to the one returned by the `size()` member function.

If there are duplicates, this solution based on `std::find()` will return the position of the first one, i.e., the first element found with the requested value `val`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`std::deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) instead:

```
#include <algorithm>

std::deque<int> names;

names.push_back(7);
names.push_back(4);
names.push_back(11);

auto it = std::find(names.begin(), names.end(), 4);
if(it != names.end())
    int distance = it - names.begin();
else
    //no element found
```

Note that `std::queue` uses `std::deque` as default implementation, so any operations take the same time as in queue.

`std::deque` also supports random access, so `names[0]` will return 7. It can also be used like any other queue:

```
std::deque<int> myDeque{};
myDeque.push_back(5);
myDeque.push_back(13);
std::cout << myDeque.front(); //5
myDeque.pop_front();
std::cout << myDeque.front(); //13
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative generic way is defining the following new container which is an inheritance of `std::queue` and defines `begin()` and `end()` returning iterators of the protected member `std::queue::c`.
Then you can use various STL algorithms with this container:

```
#include <queue>

template<
    class T,
    class Container = std::deque<T>
>
class Queue : public std::queue<T, Container>
{
public:
    using iterator               = typename Container::iterator;
    using const_iterator         = typename Container::const_iterator;
    using reverse_iterator       = typename Container::reverse_iterator;
    using const_reverse_iterator = typename Container::const_reverse_iterator;

    iterator        begin()       noexcept { return this->c. begin(); }
    const_iterator  begin() const noexcept { return this->c.cbegin(); }
    const_iterator cbegin() const noexcept { return this->c.cbegin(); }

    iterator        end()       noexcept { return this->c. end(); }
    const_iterator  end() const noexcept { return this->c.cend(); }
    const_iterator cend() const noexcept { return this->c.cend(); }

    reverse_iterator        rbegin()       noexcept  { return this->c. rbegin(); }
    const_reverse_iterator  rbegin() const noexcept  { return this->c.crbegin(); }
    const_reverse_iterator crbegin() const noexcept  { return this->c.crbegin(); }

    reverse_iterator        rend()       noexcept  { return this->c. rend(); }
    const_reverse_iterator  rend() const noexcept  { return this->c.crend(); }
    const_reverse_iterator crend() const noexcept  { return this->c.crend(); }
};
```

...Yes, as it is well known, STL containers have no virtual destructors.
The destruction of this derived class through the base class pointers causes undefined behavior.
Thus I would suggest using the above derived class if and only if you really need it.

---

For the current position problem, you can find the position where the first element found as follows:

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/06LqSDFoIF07G1Zl)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

Queue<int> q;
q.push(7);
q.push(4);
q.push(11);

const auto it = std::find(q.cbegin(), q.cend(), 4);
const auto position = std::distance(q.cbegin(), it); //should be 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also access to the underlying protected member `std::queue::c` using the following function proposed by [**these answers**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185252/is-there-a-way-to-access-the-underlying-container-of-stl-container-adaptors#3):

```
#include <queue>

template <class ADAPTER>
const auto& get_container(ADAPTER& a)
{
    struct hack : private ADAPTER {
        static auto& get(ADAPTER& a) {
            return a.*(&hack::c);
        }
    };

    return hack::get(a);
}
```

Then you can get the index of an element as follows.
This function can be also applied to other container adapters, `std::stack` and `std::priority_queue`:

[**DEMO(C++11)**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MgBm4hjf4MTfFYps)

[**DEMO(C++14 and over)**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/55OKgQYM6O90GkeL)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::queue<int> q;
    q.push(7);
    q.push(4);
    q.push(11);

    auto& c = get_container(q);

    const auto it = std::find(c.cbegin(), c.cend(), 4);
    const auto position = std::distance(c.cbegin(), it);
    std::cout << "Position is " << position << "." <<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```