# Iterate over C++ STL queue

Tags: c++

I was trying to iterate over a STL stack in c++ but was unable to do so.

Is it even possible to iterate over a C++ STL Stack or Queue without popping(Like vectors)?

Comment: A stack loses its meaning if you want to just iterate over it and it is not possible. As you suggested, you should use a vector instead of that.

Comment: You can access to the underlying protected member `std::queue::c` using the function proposed by [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185252/is-there-a-way-to-access-the-underlying-container-of-stl-container-adaptors#3).

Comment: @Hiroki but why use `std::queue` then?

Comment: @MatteoItalia Yeah, there might be no reason. I completely agree to use `std::deque` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot iterate over a `std::queue` since that is not its purpose.

A container that allows fast insertion at both ends, as well as iteration, is `std::deque`. Note that iteration is slower than for a `std::vector`, but insertion/removal at the beginning is much faster.

Comment: Friendly reminder that `std::queue` isn't an actual container, but a container adaptor whose only purpose in life is to dumb down `std::deque` interface.

Comment: @MatteoItalia You're right, thanks a lot for pointing that out.