# Converting a priority queue to vector of ints in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to convert a min-heap priority queue to return as a vector of ints. Is this type conversion is possible in C++;

Comment: Well, you could pop all the elements from the queue one by one, and push them to the vector.

Comment: There is no implicit or explicit direct conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ std::priority_queue uses a container for storage https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue

By default it is `class Container = std::vector<T>`

Is this what you want to get access to ? If so, though luck:

> C, the underlying container (protected member object)

It is not exposed. You could derive from priority_queue and expose it, if needed. But you post is thin as to what you are actually trying to do.

Keep in mind that:

- The container doesn't store sorted elements. It is a heap, so only the first element will be correct. It might have little actual use.

This answer discusses accessing the Container: [Is there a way to access the underlying container of STL container adaptors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185252)