# Why doesn't std::queue support a clear() function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, stl

I have requirement: for a function, I get the input as a stream of numbers. I mean, the function keeps on getting called with single number in each call. I am using `std::queue` for storing the stream of numbers. I need to process a collected set of numbers only when some condition is satisfied. If the condition is not satisfied I need to put all the elements into the queue and then start storing new numbers in there. For emptying the queue, I couldn't find a `clear()` method. So I am looping like this:

```
while(!q.empty())
    q.pop();
```

I got an efficient algorithm for clearing a `std::queue` at

[How do I clear the std::queue efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709146/how-do-i-clear-the-stdqueue-efficiently)

My question is: Why doesn't `std::queue` support a `clear()` function?

Since `std::deque` and `std::vector` both support a `clear()` method, what is the technical difficulty in supporting it for `std::queue`?

Or is my above use case very rare and hence not supported?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/queue/,

> queues are implemented as containers adaptors, which are classes that use an encapsulated object of a specific container class as its underlying container, providing a specific set of member functions to access it elements.

which means that the queue uses an already existing container, and is just really is an interface to this container as a FIFO queue.

This means queues are not meant to be cleared. If you need to clear a queue, this means you actually need to use an object that is not a queue, and therefore you should instead use the actual underlying container type, being a deque by default.

Comment: So I guess `std::queue` is an impaired queue meant for very limited uses, is the message?

Comment: The rationale behind the queue adapter is that items that are inserted must be extracted at some point, and not be lost using a multiple-element deletion operation. Does that make sense ? Not necessarily, since it can be cleared anyways...

Answer (score 29):

Apart from what has been said already, you *can* clear a queue very easily:

```
queue<int> q;
...
q = queue<int>(); // Assign an empty queue
```

or in C++11

```
q = {};
```

Comment: c++11 version : `q = {};`

Comment: Although, with gcc 4.9.1 `q={}` gives the error `converting to std::queue<...> from initializer list would use explicit constructor`.

Answer (score 5):

`queue` is just an adapter for some underlying container, by default a `deque`, with restricted function (as you noted here).  If you want the full blown function use the underlying `deque` instead of `queue`.

Answer (score 2):

Added this to my growing list of 'make STL readable' functions:

```
template <typename T> 
void Clear(std::queue<T>& Queue) 
{
    Queue = std::queue<T>(); // Assign to empty queue
}
```

It's just a wrapper around sellibitze's excellent answer, but means I don't have to also add a comment every time I use the technique.