# Time difference between swap and pop for for std::queue remove all of element

Tags: c++, queue, std, swap

I'm trying to clear `std::queue` so that there are already some posing about this. [How do I clear the std::queue efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709146/how-do-i-clear-the-stdqueue-efficiently)

I've tried to make a simple code for this. I have a question for time difference between "swap" and just "pop" method.

Test1 and Test2 are same total time. However, inside of method result is different.

CASE Test1: queue pop

> ```
>       Wed Jul 22 11:33:33 2015 : 10000000 start queue
>       Wed Jul 22 11:33:38 2015 : 10000000 queue push complete
>        diff : 5592 milliseconds(msec)
>       Wed Jul 22 11:33:38 2015 : 10000000 clear queue
>       Wed Jul 22 11:33:42 2015 : 10000000 queue clear complete
>        diff : 3561 milliseconds(msec)
>        diff between after TEST1 : 135644 milliseconds(msec)
> ```

CASE Test2: queue swap

> ```
>        Wed Jul 22 11:37:45 2015 : 10000000 start queue
>       Wed Jul 22 11:37:51 2015 : 10000000 queue push complete
>        diff : 5875 milliseconds(msec)
>       Wed Jul 22 11:37:51 2015 : 10000000 clear queue
>       Wed Jul 22 11:40:00 2015 : 10000000 queue clear complete
>        diff : 129130 milliseconds(msec)
>        diff between after TEST2 : 135006 milliseconds(msec)
> ```

Is there any reason why it works?

Environment:
Windows7 (x64),
MSVC2013

Code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <chrono>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

std::string asString(const std::chrono::system_clock::time_point& tp)
{
    std::time_t t = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(tp);
    std::string ts = std::ctime(&t);
    ts.resize(ts.size() - 1);
    return ts;
}

template<class T>
void clear(std::queue<T> &q)
{
    std::queue<T> empty;
    std::swap(q, empty);
}

void Test1(int itemCount, int mode)
{
    queue<int> q;
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp_push = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << asString(tp_push) << " : " << itemCount << " start queue : mode - " << mode << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
    {
        q.push(i);
    }

    std::cout << asString(std::chrono::system_clock::now()) << " : " << itemCount << " queue push complete " << endl;
    auto diff_push = std::chrono::system_clock::now() - tp_push;
    std::cout << " diff : "
        << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(diff_push).count()
        << " milliseconds(msec) " << endl;

    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp_clear = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << asString(tp_clear) << " : " << itemCount << " clear queue " << endl;

    if (mode)
    {
        clear(q);
    }
    else
    {
        while (!q.empty())
        {
        q.pop();
        }
    }

    std::cout << asString(std::chrono::system_clock::now()) << " : " << itemCount << " queue clear complete " << endl;
    auto diff_clear = std::chrono::system_clock::now() - tp_clear;
    std::cout   << " diff : "
                    << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(diff_clear).count()
                    << " milliseconds(msec) " << endl;
}

int main()
{
    try 
    {
        int itemCount = 10000000;

        std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp_test1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

        Test1(itemCount, 0);  

        auto diff_test1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now() - tp_test1;
        std::cout << " diff between after TEST1 : "
            << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(diff_test1).count()
            << " milliseconds(msec) " << endl;

        std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp_test2 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

        Test1(itemCount, 1);

        auto diff_test2 = std::chrono::system_clock::now() - tp_test2;
        std::cout << " diff after TEST2 : "
            << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(diff_test2).count()
            << " milliseconds(msec) " << endl;


    }
    catch (const exception& e)
    {
        cerr << "EXCEPTION : " << e.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `std::queue` when swapped does the equivalent of while()/pop(). This is especially true if the underlying structure is a linked list, as it would have to be iterated over each element to free up the memory.

The reason swap appears to do the same thing as the while/pop loop is because you've 'moved' the data from an empty queue into your queue object (and vice versa) - your queue object is now empty, but all you've done is move the data into a temporary queue object that is immediately freed once the Clear function returns, due to the automatic scoping of `empty` resulting in its descructor being called.